Debug OOMed Linux with low load, very low commit% and low slab
I've got a Rocky9 (RHEL-like) server with only NFS workload.
Apparently there is a memory leak and the MemUsed% went from 1% to 99% steadily. But there is no userspace program using memory (oom-killer killed nearly everything before it went panic) and also slab is pretty low. How to find who ate the memory?
Already up-to-date with distribution repo. And also tried latest el-repo LTS vanilla kernel.
/proc/meminfo moments before it OOMed and crashed:
MemTotal:       394292660 kB
MemFree:         1551296 kB
MemAvailable:    6776108 kB
Buffers:            1712 kB
Cached:          7340144 kB
SwapCached:         4308 kB
Active:           325936 kB
Inactive:        7071836 kB
...
KReclaimable:     129816 kB
Slab:             331596 kB
SReclaimable:     129816 kB
SUnreclaim:       201780 kB
...
VmallocUsed:      319528 kB

Filed a bug on kernel.org but no response after a week. Log files such as dmesg, vmallocinfo and lsmod were attached there.

Perhaps disable memory overcommit and see what complains the most about not being able to get memory?  But make sure you have shell access that won't time out before you start such an experiment.

@AndrewHenle Sure, I'll have a try. I've echo 80 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio ; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory and left a logged-in shell on console.

Why truncate the meminfo? Where is the rest of it? Did you get a task dump also from the OOM?

Sometimes such behavior is also caused by hardware failures. My personal computer had once such failure, where a usual default ubuntu without any customization would use more and more memory until the point when a OOM error came. A BIOS update helped in my case.
